# Implementing Facebook comments widget in iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api, uiwebview

A lot of websites allow you to post comments through your Facebook account, and I wanted some pointers of how to port this feature into iOS. The iOS app I am working on authenticates users via Facebook login (using FB SDK) and I initially considered using a UIWebView which links to another site that stores all the comments. The issue with this was that UIWebView forces you to login to Facebook again when you want to post a comment, and it's not possible to use the login token during the authentication phase to login to Facebook in the UIWebView. In other words, despite having to login to Facebook when you start the app, a user must login a second time to post comments on the UIWebView page (I am pretty sure this is due to security purposes). Any alternative ways to implement a Facebook comments widget without having to authenticate twice in my app would be great. Thanks!